# Why does the mobile-version navbar pops up automatically when downsizing screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar

I am doing a side project about a movie website. I designed an RWD navbar as following. When I downsize the screen to the break point which is 576px, the mobile-version navbar would pop up automatically then hide. The result can be seen if running the snippet then expand and collapse the window. I guess the checkbox causes this issue but not really sure. Could someone help me with this issue, please? Thank you!

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#checked {
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -9999;
  position: absolute;
}

#checked:checked ~.navbar {
  right: 0;
}

.logo {
  height: 60%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar{
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  right: -100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: .4s;
}

.navbar a:hover, .hideBtn:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}

.navbar a,
 .hideBtn, .showBtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.showBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  right: 10px;
}

.showcase {
  position: relative;
  background: url("./image/photo-1517604931442-7e0c8ed2963c.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.showcase .mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.showcase .txt, 
.showcase .slogan {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.showcase .slogan {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  bottom: 35%;
}

.service {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: #000;
  grid-gap:20px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
}

.service a {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.service a img {
  width: 30%;
}

.service a p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 10px;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

.content div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.content div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.content div img {
  width: 100%;
}

.content div p {
    padding: 10px;
  }

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.contact-txt {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

footer #social-media img{
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .showBtn, .navbar .hideBtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar{
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  transition: none;
  z-index: 0;
}
  .showcase .txt {
    font-size: 4em;
  }

  .showcase .slogan {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  .service {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  .content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  .content div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Movie List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <header>
      <img class="logo" src="./image/media.svg" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="checked">
      <label for="checked" class="showBtn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="./explore.html">Explore</a>
        <a href="#social-media">Contact us</a>
        <label for="checked" class="hideBtn">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </label>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="showcase">
      <div class="mask"></div>
      <h1 class="txt">HOME CINEMA</h1>
      <h2 class="slogan">Experience Cinema at home</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
      <a href="#subscribe-info">
        <img src="./image/communications.svg" alt="">
        <p>$99 / month</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#vr-info">
        <img src="./image/electronics.svg" alt="">
        <p>Virtual Reality</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#unlimited-info">
        <img src="./image/arrows.svg" alt="">
        <p>Unlimited Watch</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="subscribe-info">
        <img src="./image/photo-1543536448-d209d2d13a1c.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis necessitatibus ratione, ut sunt
          voluptatibus totam a repudiandae enim nihil beatae ducimus aliquid! Et, beatae reprehenderit aspernatur est
          hic commodi expedita.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="vr-info">
        <img src="./image/pexels-photo-3391378.jpeg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque possimus facere ipsum unde saepe maxime
          voluptatem tempora sint pariatur at, nobis ipsam necessitatibus similique maiores, reiciendis repudiandae
          voluptatum, cumque repellat.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="unlimited-info">
        <img src="./image/pexels-photo-3912397.jpeg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, nesciunt veniam, reprehenderit, fugiat nemo
          fugit natus dicta maxime delectus ut quos et mollitia obcaecati pariatur. Rerum minima delectus sint ex?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="contact-info">
        <div class="contact-txt">
          <p>hola@jamondetaiwan.com</p>
          <p>+886 2771 5412</p>
          <p>2F., No. 2, Ln. 179, Kanghu Rd., Neihu Dist., Taipei City 114, Taiwan (R.O.C.)</p>
        </div>
        <div id="social-media">
          <img src="./image/fb.svg" alt="">
          <img src="./image/ig.svg" alt="">
          <img src="./image/youtube.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This arises due to the CSS `transition: .5s;` in `.navbar`; when you reach the breakpoint, you are changing the `right` position and CSS is animating it. To avoid this, specify the properties you want to animate or add the `transition` property using JavaScript before you show the menu. For example, using jQuery:

`$(".navbar").css("transition", ".5s");`

**Edit**: I missed the CSS selector that is causing the animation and so assumed it was jQuery.

To address the issue with just HTML/CSS, you can create a copy of the navbar and use `display: none;`. The following snippet should work; I have added a copy of the navbar and added the classes `.navbar-big` and `.navbar-small`. This allow us to use the `display` property to hide the navbar we don't want to show based on the breakpoint, and set `transition: right .5s;` for `.navbar-small`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#checked {
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -9999;
  position: absolute;
}

#checked:checked ~.navbar {
  right: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.logo {
  height: 60%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar {
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  right: -100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-small {
  transition: right .5s;
}

.navbar-big {
  display: none;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: .4s;
}

.navbar a:hover, .hideBtn:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}

.navbar a,
 .hideBtn, .showBtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.showBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  right: 10px;
}

.showcase {
  position: relative;
  background: url("./image/photo-1517604931442-7e0c8ed2963c.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.showcase .mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.showcase .txt, 
.showcase .slogan {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.showcase .slogan {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  bottom: 35%;
}

.service {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: #000;
  grid-gap:20px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
}

.service a {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.service a img {
  width: 30%;
}

.service a p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 10px;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

.content div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.content div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.content div img {
  width: 100%;
}

.content div p {
    padding: 10px;
  }

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.contact-txt {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

footer #social-media img{
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .showBtn, .navbar .hideBtn {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar {
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  transition: none;
  z-index: 0;
  }

  .navbar-small {
    display: none;
  }

  .showcase .txt {
    font-size: 4em;
  }

  .showcase .slogan {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  .service {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  .content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  .content div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Movie List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <header>
      <img class="logo" src="./image/media.svg" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="checked">
      <label for="checked" class="showBtn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-big">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="./explore.html">Explore</a>
        <a href="#social-media">Contact us</a>
        <label for="checked" class="hideBtn">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </label>
      </nav>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-small">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="./explore.html">Explore</a>
        <a href="#social-media">Contact us</a>
        <label for="checked" class="hideBtn">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </label>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="showcase">
      <div class="mask"></div>
      <h1 class="txt">HOME CINEMA</h1>
      <h2 class="slogan">Experience Cinema at home</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
      <a href="#subscribe-info">
        <img src="./image/communications.svg" alt="">
        <p>$99 / month</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#vr-info">
        <img src="./image/electronics.svg" alt="">
        <p>Virtual Reality</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#unlimited-info">
        <img src="./image/arrows.svg" alt="">
        <p>Unlimited Watch</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="subscribe-info">
        <img src="./image/photo-1543536448-d209d2d13a1c.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis necessitatibus ratione, ut sunt
          voluptatibus totam a repudiandae enim nihil beatae ducimus aliquid! Et, beatae reprehenderit aspernatur est
          hic commodi expedita.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="vr-info">
        <img src="./image/pexels-photo-3391378.jpeg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque possimus facere ipsum unde saepe maxime
          voluptatem tempora sint pariatur at, nobis ipsam necessitatibus similique maiores, reiciendis repudiandae
          voluptatum, cumque repellat.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="unlimited-info">
        <img src="./image/pexels-photo-3912397.jpeg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, nesciunt veniam, reprehenderit, fugiat nemo
          fugit natus dicta maxime delectus ut quos et mollitia obcaecati pariatur. Rerum minima delectus sint ex?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="contact-info">
        <div class="contact-txt">
          <p>hola@jamondetaiwan.com</p>
          <p>+886 2771 5412</p>
          <p>2F., No. 2, Ln. 179, Kanghu Rd., Neihu Dist., Taipei City 114, Taiwan (R.O.C.)</p>
        </div>
        <div id="social-media">
          <img src="./image/fb.svg" alt="">
          <img src="./image/ig.svg" alt="">
          <img src="./image/youtube.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. If I understand correctly, you mean the transition's property can not be set transform? How should I revise the transition property if only using CSS? Thank you!

Comment: @Charlotte I have edited my answer to avoid using jQuery. I assumed you were using it before - my mistake!